# How to create bidirectional predicates in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

In Prolog, there are predicates that are *bidirectional* (or even *"multidirectional"*), in the sense that one can split the set of variables into input and output variables in many different ways. For example, the predicate `number_string` acts like a bijection in both directions:

```
number_string(N, "42"). % finds solution N = 42
number_string(42, S).   % finds solution S = "42"
```

However, this wonderful property does not seem to be preserved by the conjunction of clauses. For example, consider the following two predicates, which simply translate strings like `3x^2` into pieces of an abstract syntax tree like `term(3,2)`:

```
parse_stuff(String, term(Coeff, Pow)) :- 
  string_concat(CoeffStr, MonomialStr, String),
  string_concat("x^", PowStr, MonomialStr),
  number_string(Coeff, CoeffStr),
  number_string(Pow, PowStr).

write_stuff(String, term(Coeff, Pow)) :- 
  number_string(Pow, PowStr),
  number_string(Coeff, CoeffStr),
  string_concat("x^", PowStr, MonomialStr),
  string_concat(CoeffStr, MonomialStr, String).
```

Both predicates are exactly the same, except that the order of the defining clauses on the right hand side is reversed. All clauses on the right hand side are themselves bidirectional.

Here is an example session:

```
?- parse_stuff("3x^2", X).
X = term(3, 2).

?- parse_stuff(X, term(3, 2)).
ERROR: string_concat/3: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated

?- write_stuff(X, term(3, 2)).
X = "3x^2".

?- write_stuff("3x^2", X).
ERROR: number_string/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Both predicates work only in one way, although they both are obviously bijections, which is pretty sad.

The question consists of two parts (there are two requirements: easy to use, easy to maintain):

1. Is there any robust way to build bidirectional predicates in Prolog?
2. Is it possible to avoid code-duplication (that is, maintaining two versions: one normal, one reversed)?

Maybe there is some flag that tells "reverse the order of clauses if necessary"?

I'm currently using SWI-Prolog 7.1.x, if it's relevant.

---

[**↓ Jump to my own answer ↓**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29952316/2707792)

Comment: To be clear, the *general* question of how to build relational predicates in prolog is not answered (it would be difficult to answer, since there's no simple process which applies to all predicate). The answer provided applies to your specific problem.

Comment: I would already be satisfied if I could somehow chain "obvious bijections". Some way to build a predicate from a list of clauses or something like that would do. I suspect that something like this should be *somewhere* out there in the swi-documentation, but I can't find it.

Comment: Is there any example of a predicate implementable or included in pure Prolog, which is not usable in both directions? All the examples, which are not usable in both directions, use non-logical components like the arithmetic is

Comment: Now I can answer my comment myself: An example in pure Prolog is: ````last([ |R],E) :- last(R,E).
last([E],E).````, which results in an infinite loop for ````last(L, 1)````, but not for ````last([1], E)````.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this: either you use an extra argument stating what the order should be and implement a top-predicate that chooses which of your predicates to use on the base of it, or you write a top-predicate that makes the choice by testing which arguments are free with no need for external information. In the latter you will probably use the `var/1` or `nonvar/1` extra-logical predefined predicates; I used extensively this in making Definite-Clause Grammars reversible, so that they could be used for parsing and for generating text, in that way avoiding a lot of work both in writing the programs and maintaining them.

**UPDATE** in answer to the additional requirement.

To avoid code duplication you should try to identify the common parts in both versions and define predicates for each part. You then call these predicates where needed instead of having their code in many places.
But this is not really useful in your example that is too small: maybe you can try using difference lists and avoiding the concatenations to simplify your predicates.

Comment: Thank you very much! Such a top-predicate would at least make it comfortable for the user. But this does not solve the problem that we have to maintain two versions of essentially the same predicate. I edited my question in order to clarify that I'm interested in both ease of use and maintainability. But your proposal at least solves the problem with the ease of use, that's already one half of what I wanted, thanks.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin in some cases, a predicate can be refactored to be more *relational* (what you're calling *bidirectional*). But there's not always such an elegant solution.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin You are welcome. I updated my answer above. Avoiding duplicates is a general issue even when predicates are not relational, that is why I did not mention it from the start.

Comment: @migfilg Well, that's certainly a valuable general remark, but not quite what I hoped for. I'll just play around with the proposals a little bit, and then probably accept your answer, if no one else comes up with some sort of "reverseClauses"-macro or something. Thanks so far.

Comment: Accepted for pointing in the right direction (I used `free_variables` after all). I posted a version that chains bijections as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Systematically chaining bijections [My own answer]**

Advantages:

- Produces a bidirectional predicate from a chain of bijection-predicates.
- Avoids any code duplication.
- No explicit specification of the order is required.

Drawbacks:

- Suppresses warnings about unused free variables
- Uses "reflection" (might have impact on performance of compiled code)

Here is how we can chain multiple predicates that are obviously bijections:

```
% suppresses "Singleton variables" warning for
% a single variable
suppress_singleton_warning(_).

% calls all clauses in a list.
call_all([]).
call_all([F|G]) :- 
  call(F),call_all(G).

% If `X` is a closed term, calls all clauses `FS`
% in left-to-right order.
bijection(X, FS, Y) :-
  suppress_singleton_warning(Y),
  free_variables(X, XVars), 
  XVars == [],
  call_all(FS).

% If `Y` is a closed term, calls all clauses `FS`
% in right-to-left order
bijection(X, FS, Y) :-
  suppress_singleton_warning(X),
  free_variables(Y, YVars), 
  YVars == [],
  reverse(FS, RevFS),
  call_all(RevFS).
```

Example usage:

```
% Example: parser/printer that works in both
% directions.
parse_stuff(String, term(Coeff, Pow)) :-
  Clauses = [
    string_concat(CoeffStr, MonomialStr, String),
    string_concat("x^", PowStr, MonomialStr),
    number_string(Coeff, CoeffStr),
    number_string(Pow, PowStr)
  ],
  bijection(String, Clauses, term(Coeff, Pow)).
```

One can also just as well pass the `Clauses` directly, no extra variable is needed. This works as expected, in both directions:

```
 parse_stuff("3x^2", T), write(T), nl,
 parse_stuff(X, term(3,2)), write(X), nl
```

gives:

```
term(3,2)
3x^2
```

Comment: The problem I see with this approach is that it only works if the list of clauses in one case is the reverse of the list in the other. In general it may be difficult to follow this requirement.

Comment: This is *always* the case, as long as we are simply chaining relations. If one wants to compute inverse of a chain of relations, then by definition, one has to chain the inverses in reverse order. This does not apply to relations that are not linear chains of bidirectional directions, but I didn't claim that it would. In the more general case, one would have to compute an appropriate topological sorting first.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation: I was not aware of the special meaning of *chaining* in this context.

Comment: This answer is incredible, thanks for going down this rabbit hole! I'll add that, as far as I understand it, Mercury language does this kind of re-ordering / topological sorting automatically

Comment: You don't need to "suppress singleton variables": Simply use `_` instead of `X` and `Y` when you do not need them. You can also use `[]` in `free_vaiables/2`. You can use `maplist(call, Goals)`.

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar snag writing a clause to give numbers a 'n' prefix so they can be used as functors, which I wanted to later convert back from say n1 to 1. I ended up with this somewhat inelegant solution, which works:

```
number_to_identifier(Number, Identifier) :-
  ground(Number) ->
   (number(Number),
    number_string(Number, String1),
    string_concat('n', String1, String2),
    atom_string(Identifier, String2))
   ;
   (atom(Identifier),
    atom_string(Identifier, String2),
    string_concat('n', String1, String2),
    number_string(Number, String1)).
```